# Drag Drop File with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am missing something but I'm not sure what it could be...

I'm trying to push the Base 64 code version of a drag-dropped file into a text area... but for some reason it's not working...

Anyone care to tell me where I'm going wrong with the code? This is new territory for me...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function processFile(file){
        var o = $("#fileInfo");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
        o.innerHTML = e.target.result.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
        }
        reader.readAsURL(file);
    }

    // Sets up dataTransfer event
    jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');

    // Bind drop to drop zone
    $('#drop-files').bind('drop', function(e) {
        // Prevents element from default function
        e.preventDefault();
        // Grabs list of files
        var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        // Loop through files...
        $.each(files, function(index, file) {
            processFile(files[index]);
        });
    });
});
```

I'm seriously not sure where I have screwed up... eventually I will be pushing this to an upload page of my own choosing... but for now I want to at least get the Base64 code of the very first file to show in that text area ("fileInfo").

Appreciate any thoughts here...

Answer (score 2):

The `o` represents `jQuery` object and you can not access `DOM` object property `innerHTML` on it. Either call [**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) on `o` or make it `DOM` object using `indexer`.

Change

```
o.innerHTML = e.target.result.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

To

```
o.html(e.target.result.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");)
```

or

```
o[0].innerHTML = e.target.result.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

Comment: I should have noticed that earlier... but now that I've implemented that I'm getting the error: "reader.readAsURL" is not a function... I was under the assumption that readAsURL was an available function using Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out what had happened...

The line:

```
reader.readAsURL(file);
```

should read:

```
reader.readAsURLData(file);
```

*shaking my head*

But I've now found another little issue which I will post later...

Thanks for your efforts...